# how to add new items in listbox using VBA in ms access

Tags: ms-access-2007

How to add new items in listbox using VBA in ms access. i tried listbox.addnew property in VBA but facing error.

i actully wrote list6.addnew (Hotel_Name,id). Here Hotel_Name is the variable holding name of hotel and Id is holding primary key value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used several methods to populate a listbox.

1. Directly in the property sheet of the listbox, set the Row Source to:

   ```
   SELECT tblTable.Field, qryQuery.Field FROM tblTable
   ```

Throw in some AS after each field name and you can rename the headers the listbox creates so that it is easier to read on the form than your table or query field names  Add a WHERE statement to filter as you need it.  You can get results from tables, queries, or both.

1. Same sort of thing in VBA:

   ```
   Dim rec As DAO.Recordset, sql As String
   sql = "SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4 FROM tblTable WHERE Field1 = "Filter Example"
        Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql)

   listbox0.column0 = rec(0)
   listbox0.column1 = rec(1)
   listbox0.column2 = rec(2)
   listbox0.column3 = rec(3)
   ```

Those are the two I would recommend.  The Property sheet method is quick and easy, but harder to track and modify in development than the VBA method.  (VBA has a good FIND tool built in to search for specific string values)